# JavaScript to generate the questions using random numbers using Select operators randomly(+,*,-) for each equation

Tags: javascript

I want to do this math game that generates numbers and operators randomly.

This is hint - `x = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);` will generate a random number between 0 and 100. Select operators randomly `(+,*,-)` for each equation. Please any one can help me.

```js
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 8){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
document.write(arr);
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: `var arr = []
while(arr.length < 8){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
document.write(arr);` I wrote like this code for take random numbers. this is working properly. Now, I need to add math operations for that. How I can do that.@Andreas

Comment: ok, edited. @Andreas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an ES6 implementation of that, I used `console.log` instead of `document.write`

```js
let questionsCount = 10;

function generateQuestions() {
    let questions = []; 

    for(let i = 0;i < questionsCount;i++) {
      let n1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      let n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      let operatorObj = randomOperator(n1,n2)
      questions.push({
         question: `${n1} ${operatorObj.operator} ${n2} ?`,
         answer: operatorObj.answer
      });
    }

    return questions;
}




 function randomOperator(n1,n2) {
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    switch (n) {
       case 0: 
         return {operator: '+', answer: n1 + n2};
       case 1:
         return {operator: '-', answer: n1 - n2}
       case 2:
         return {operator: '*', answer: n1 * n2}
       case 3:
         return {operator: '/', answer: n1 / n2}
    }
 }

let questions = generateQuestions();

let answers = questions.map((question) => 
     prompt(question.question));

answers.forEach((answer,i) => {
    console.log(`${questions[i].question} ${answer} ${(answer == 
       questions[i].answer) ? 'Correct': `Wrong should be 
       ${questions[i].answer}`}`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend, how to add 2 marks per correct answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch-case` statement to select the operator and use `Math.random()` to randomize it

```
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 8){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}

for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    operator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch(operator) {
        case 0:
            eval(prompt(arr[i*2] + " + " + arr[i*2+1]));
            break;
        case 1:
            eval(prompt(arr[i*2] + " - " + arr[i*2+1]));
            break;
        case 2:
            eval(prompt(arr[i*2] + " * " + arr[i*2+1]));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to show this equation in `prompt`. I wrote like this, but this is not working properly. `eval(prompt (" + "));`

Comment: Edited my answer to use `eval(prompt())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend, how to add 2 marks per correct answer)

Comment: Please attempt that by yourself first

Answer (score 0):

`Better solution:` While it doesn't use prompts I'm sure you can figure that part out.
works best on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQyMyz/), and not very well inside the awkward snippet
feature that stack-overflow provides (due to the reset button triggering reload)
here's the code in case your interested:

```js
//Solve the equation - math problem game

//change * 4 if you want more operators then add the
//operator as a string inside the operator array...
//you may also add duplicate operators to increase odds
//higher odds of harder operator = harder mode
var a = location;
function start() {
document.body.innerHTML = null;
var operators = ["/", "*", "-", "+"],
  arr = [],
  arrCompiled,
  i = 0, a = location;
while (arr.length < 8) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
while(i < arr.length) {
  var oper = ' '+operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]+' ';
  if (i === 0) {
    arrCompiled = arr.toString()
.replace(/,/, oper);
  }
  
  arrCompiled = arrCompiled.replace(/,/, oper);
  i++;
}
document.write('<div id="questions">'+arrCompiled+' = ???</div>');
document.getElementById("questions").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<button id="solve">Solve</button>');
}
start();

document.getElementById('solve').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('solve')) {
  var x = document.getElementById('questions').innerText.replace(/\?/g, "");
  var y = x.replace(/[^0-9*/+-.()]+/g, "");
  var z = Math.round(eval(y) * 100) / 100;
  document.write(x + z + ' - solved <a href="javascript:a.reload();"><button>New Problem</button></a>');
  document.getElementById('questions').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the your answer my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 8){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
document.write(arr);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).